# $http get service is not shows first time after cache and refresh it shows

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I have been trying to figure it out, why my get request does not shows data on first time of loading to application, i have implemented angularjs with REST, spring MVC and hibernate.

```
app.controller("HeaderCtrl", ["$scope","$http", function($scope,$http) 
 {
  $http.get('..../getHeaderContent').success(function(data) {
    $scope.header = data;
  }).error(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
 }
]);
```

Comment: it is calling first time too check https://jsfiddle.net/ejm9nb5v/

Comment: @GurdeepSingh , could you please brief little more about your issue

Comment: explain more or share stacktrace or more code

Comment: @Pramod_Para i m face the issue when application runs first time, if i reload chrome and remove cache then get API works fine. And one more thing my application is a combination of spring, hibernate, Rest and angularjs

Comment: You mean to say, your request only works once?

Comment: @Pramod_Para no, it works fine until i wont refresh chrome